# ASP: execute jquery function in C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

SO a quick question: I would like to execute a certain Jquery function in my view.

I have a function

function doSomething() {
             $('#page'). ...
        });
}

Only when @if (TempData["check"] != null) { ... then the function should be called.

In all examples I can find online a function can either be called from the (document).ready function or from pressing a button.

My question: how dou you execute a jquery from a dhtml

I am using MVC4 with razor

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

In the HTML portion of the page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
        ...
    });
</script>
```

?

make sure you're also loading your jquery file somewhere in that page's DOM.  Adding

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

right above the opening script tag above should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

actually i solved it, i don't have a lot of javascript knowledge but it was a simple as calling the function, but within script tags.

`@if(TempData["check"] != null){`

`<script>doSomething()</script>}`